# Monochromatic Tree

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that for any tree $T$ and whole number $g$ there is some graph $G$ without cycles of length at most $g$ such that in any coloring of the edges of $G$ in 2 -colors there is a monochromatic copy of $T$.

I have no idea how to approach this. Thanks

Comment: By any coloring do you mean any proper coloring?

Comment: Any coloring. (need not be proper)

Comment: Do you need the $T$ to be a spanning tree of $G$ (as in the title)?

Comment: That would not be possible. Take the case where $T$ is on $g$ vertices.

Comment: The monochromatic T need not span G.

Answer (score 1):

Here's few facts you could use.

**Fact 1:**

> If $T$ is tree on $k$ vertcices and $G$ is graph with $\delta(G) \ge k$, then $G$ contains a copy of $T$

This fact could be proven by induction on $k$.

**Fact 2:**

> For all $d$, $g$ positive integers, there is a graph $G_{d, g}$ with $\delta(G_{d, g}) \ge d$, and the girth of $G_{d, g}$ greater or equal to $g$

This could be proven using the probabilistic method.

**Fact 3:**

> Every graph $G$ contains a subgraph $H$ with $\delta(H) \ge \frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$

This could be proven by induction on the number of vertices of $G$.

**Fact 4:**

> If the edges of a graph $G$ is partitioned into two parts $E_1$ and $E_2$, then either $\frac{|E_1|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac{|E(G)|}{2|V(G)|}$ or $\frac{|E_2|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac{|E(G)|}{2|V(G)|}$

By pigeonhole principle.

Putting some of those facts together will wield a proof to the statement.